# How to call java script function in seperate .js file in android?

Tags: javascript, android

I am new to webview. The question is how to call function from an external .js file in Android? I tried sample basic functionality.

I have a simple function `printMyName()` in the *scripting.js* file in assets folder. I am trying something like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/js/script.js");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:printMyName();");
```

**Output:** The function is displaying in the webview.